# Issues with Wordpress Pagenation

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I made a home template for my site to manage the displaying of all posts on it. The template is meant to be displaying 6 posts at a time; three in each row, on top of each other. The rest I placed behind WP pagination. This is a snippet of the pagination code:

```php
$total_posts = $query->found_posts;
$posts_per_page = $query->get('posts_per_page');
$current_page = max(1, $paged);

if ($total_pages = $query->max_num_pages) {
  echo '<div class="pagination">';
  
  // Calculate the range of posts being shown
  $start_post = ($current_page - 1) * $posts_per_page + 1;
  $end_post = min($start_post + $posts_per_page - 1, $total_posts);
  
  echo sprintf(__('Showing %d-%d of %d', 'your-text-domain'), $start_post, $end_post, $total_posts);
  
  echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => get_pagenum_link() . '%_%',
    'format' => '/page/%#%',
    'current' => $current_page,
    'total' => $total_pages,
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Prev'),
    'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
  ));
  
  echo '</div>';
}

else 
  echo '<p>No posts found.</p>';
        endif;
        ?>

      </div>
```

The problem I am having is with the displaying of other pages. When I click on `page2`, or next, I'm brought to a 404. I assigned a posts page to the site and named that page Articles. This is the page I assigned my template to. I set my permalinks to Postname so this is what the page URL comes up as; `http://localhost/open-wordpress1/articles/`. This page works, but when I click on the next or page2 buttons, this pagination URL, `http://localhost/open-wordpress1/articles/page/2`, brings up the 404 templates. How can I make it such that the pagination doesn't give me 404s? Kindly assist...